# Audit property change in model

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I need to be able to audit changes for several Model in my Spring MVC - JPA application. I have class USER:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;
@Column(unique = true)
private String email;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String password;
private Date birthday;
private String mobileNumber;
private Date lastLogedInDate;
private int failedLoginsCount;
private Date lastFailedLoginDate;
private Date lastPasswordResetDate;
private boolean isAdministrator;
private String screenName;
@Column(nullable = true, columnDefinition = "VARBINARY(MAX)")
private byte[] image;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
@OneToOne
private Branch branch;
```

I want to be able to audit changes of fields mobileNumber, screenName and branch
and I want to be able to have enough data to reverse the previous state of user. By reverse I mean that I have activity list for this user and will have a button - and while pressing it reverse previous state for certain field(branch , screenName or mobileName). I also want to implement such functionality on 10 different Models in my application.

I have read about hibernate canvas(but have never tried it) - can I audit such changes for certain fields only? how much this will effect the speed of my application?

Is there any other ready made solution for doing this? or I have to check for changes manually?

Comment: That is what `hibernate-envers` can do...

Comment: what about performance? won't it slow down the process of update or delete functions for my application?

Comment: Everything you do will slow down things, even if you build your own.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact use case for AOP, one of the major benefits of using a DI container like Spring. Read [this article](http://www.idanfridman.com/clean-auditing-infrastructure-for-your-app-using-aop-custom-annotations-and-reflection/) for more information.